# Eager initialization vs Lazy initialization use case

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, global-variables

I have a usecase where I have a code like this:

```
public class Xapp extends App {
     private A a;
     private B b;
     private C c;

     public Xapp() {
        // do anything
     }

     @override
     public void doStuff() {
       try{
          do1();
          do2();
          do3()
       } catch(Exception e) {
           throw new XappException(msg);
       }
     }

     public void do1() {
         a = new A();
         a.process();
     }

     public void do2() {
         b = new B();
         b.process();
     }

     public void do3() {
         c = new C();
         c.process();
     }

}
```

It will be called from TopApp class inside main as:(strict requirement)

```
new Xapp.doStuff()
```

Here, initialization of B depends on what **A** processes and initialization of **C** depends on what **A** and **B** processes. Hence I am initializating in an iterative fashion.(**lazy initialization**).

But somebody told me the design should be strictly done such that every constructor(**A**, **B** and **C**) initialization should be done in Xapp constructor only. (**eager initialization**)

**I somehow don't agree**. Because my code flow is iterative in way of producer and consumer. Generally we do eager initialization when resources are available. But here I can't because the resources will be processed iteratively by A then B then C.

I find this approach to be perfect. Are there any design flaws?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I suspect someone's reacting to the fact that you didn't include the code for `A`, `B` and `C`, and the hidden dependencies implied by _"...initialization of B depends on what A processes..."_, which are not visible.  You did the right thing trying to create a [mcve] but just didn't carry it to completion.  I think it's a good question if you finish the MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common pattern for when you cannot do the initialization in the constructor, is to make the constructor private and have a static method return the new, fully initialized instance.

```
public class Xapp extends App {
     private A a;
     private B b;
     private C c;

     private Xapp() {
        // do anything
     }

     public static Xapp newInstance() {
         Xapp x = new Xapp();
         x.doStuff();
         return x
     }

     // snip...

}
```

This is especially useful when your class can be inherited, because calling non-private methods in a constructor can be problematic if a sublcass overrides them due to initialization order.

Comment: This is not a singleton. It's just a way to defer initialization until after the object is constructed, but provide an API such that the caller receives a fully initialized instance.

Comment: Here doStuff is overriden method of interface App, and in main app TopApp class I need to call like new Xapp.doStuff() only.